# Materialize's responsive utilites not working

Tags: css, html, materialize

I can't understand why the utilities "show-on-small" and so on do not work. Even though the following script should only show on small, it shows all the time (please note that other materialize classes work, so it's not that I can't access their files).

Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="show-on-small"> <p  style="color: black" class="show-on-medium">Only smaall</p></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at what `.show-on-small` does, we can clearly see it never **hides** the element. It only **makes sure it is shown on small**:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .show-on-small{
    display:block !important
  }
}
```

So the next example will work:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<p class="show-on-small" style="display:none;">I only show on small</p>
```

... because it has `display:none` on all cases, except on small where it is overridden by Materialize's CSS with `!important`.

Do note you can also use `.hide-on-*` classes in Materialize, which do what you seem to want.

Comment: Isn't it bad syntax to have inline styling just to hide a div. I mean most search engines don't like inline styling?

Comment: @SuperDJ, inline styling and SEO have nothing to do with each other. Inline styling is (really) bad for completely different reasons. In short, it adds unnecessary complexity to code and makes maintaining the code much harder. For the purpose of demonstrating a principle, I'd say it's perfectly fine. If I added a class that applied `display:none` to the element above, the way `.show-on-*` works would have been less clear. Additionally, I'm also implicitly stating: **"it even overrides inline styling"**, which is rather important for current and future users benefiting from the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hide-on-med-and-up` which sets `display: none` for screens bigger than 601px in width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/><!-- Do you have this line? -->
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <div class="hide-on-med-and-up">Only smaall</div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Their files can be found at https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize. From there you could also contribute.

Comment: Since you took the time to suggest improvements for my answer, I'll return the favor. Usage of "You can try ..." should be avoided in answers. It makes it look like you don't know the source of the bug for sure but suggest some stuff that might work. Also note I added my answer as (at the time I did it) I felt like your answer lacks clarity in expressing the exact reason for which OP's code does not perform as they expect it to. That's why I emphasized it. In short, you need to ask yourself: 1. what does the user expect? 2. why doesn't it happen? 3. How can I explain as clearly as possible?

Comment: Ref: *"there doesn't seem to be any media queries related to the `.show-on-small`"*: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/dist/css/materialize.css#L2922

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu When I initially inspected the element it didn't show that styling. Wasn't really suggesting improvements for your answer, just wondered why you would do it like that and if there wasn't any drawbacks for it. But thanks for highlighting the improvements.

Answer (score 0):

For only showing on mobile use .hide-on-med-and-up
It will work